# Sum to infinity of reciprocal of arithmetic sequence terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Is there a arithmetic sequence starting at any a, such that the sum of the reciprocals of its terms to infinity converges?
i.e. 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{a+nd}=\frac 1a+\frac 1{a+d}+\frac 1{a+2d} +\frac 1{a+3d}\cdots $ converges for any a or d

Comment: No.  All such sequences are comparable to $\sum \frac 1n$ which diverges.

Comment: Ah cool that's what I thought, do you just apply the transformation n=(1-a)/d without affecting the upper bound of the sum?

Comment: Easier to work with limits.  Let $A_n=\frac 1{a+nd},B_n=\frac 1n$ and compute $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {A_n}{B_n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply observe that

$$\frac 1{a+nd}\sim \frac 1{nd}$$

then the given series diverges by limit comparison test with the harmonic series $\sum \frac 1{n}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let the $n^{th}$ term be $a_n=\frac{1}{a+nd}$
Then, $a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac{-d}{a^2+n\left(n-1\right)d^2+\left(2n-1\right)}$
Which decreases at a very small rate which means the series diverges